# Adding and deleting directory to vim interpreters’ import path

Tags: vim, scheme, racket

What is the mzscheme equivalent of the following codes?

- python:

  ```
  python import sys, vim
  python sys.path.append(vim.eval("var"))
  <...>
  python sys.path.remove(vim.eval("var"))
  ```
- perl:

  ```
  perl push @INC, [VIM::Eval("var")]->[1];
  <...>
  perl @INC=(grep {$_ ne VIM::Eval("var")} @INC);
  ```
- lua:

  ```
  let str=';'.var.'/?.lua;'.var.'/?/init.lua'
  lua package.path=package.path..vim.eval("str")
  <...>
  let ppath=[]
  lua vim.eval("add(ppath,"..string.format("%q", package.path)..")")
  let importidx=stridx(ppath[0], str)
  let importendidx=importidx+len(str)
  let ppath[0]=((importidx>0)?(ppath[0][:(importidx-1)]):("")).
              \ppath[0][(importendidx+1):]
  lua package.path=vim.eval("ppath[0]")
  ```
- ruby:

  ```
  ruby $LOAD_PATH << VIM::evaluate("var")
  <...>
  ruby $LOAD_PATH.delete(VIM::evaluate("var"))
  ```
- tcl:

  ```
  silent tcl lappend auto_path [::vim::expr "dir"]
  <...>
  silent tcl set auto_path
              \ [lreplace $auto_path
              \ {*}[lrepeat 2
              \ [lsearch -exact $auto_path
              \ [::vim::expr "a:fdict.imported"]]]]
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what you want to do with your script. [Racket](http://www.racket-lang.org) (it hasn't been called "mzscheme" for a long time now) works with modules, so you rarely use the "add a path to a dynamic load path" kind of workflow. Instead, modules are imported using the `require` form from either the core collection of libraries or from packages you've installed.

If you *really* need to load things dynamically, one option is to set the [`current-directory`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?q=current-directory#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._current-directory))) parameter and then use [`dynamic-require`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Module_Names_and_Loading.html?q=dynamic-require#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._dynamic-require))).

```
(require (prefix-in vim- vimext))
(parameterize ([current-directory (vim-eval "var")])
  (define add (dynamic-require "add.rkt" 'add)))
```

The `dynamic-require` will pull out the `add` function from the `add.rkt` file in the supplied directory. Note: I haven't tested this code since I can't find a version of vim that has Racket support compiled in.

You can find the documentation for the vim interface in Racket [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_mzsch.html). General documentation for Racket [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/index.html).

Comment: Packages you have installed how? What I need is to make frawor users able to add directory to theirs plugins that will be taken as module import path without requiring them to add this path by themselves. I’ve never seen lua, tcl or racket/mzscheme requiring plugins, thus code for them is only for completeness. Could you say what a typical racket user will do when he wants to have his racket source code utilizing vim interface to be contained in a separate file with only a few functions called from the mappings/commands?

Comment: If you need to require functions from another file (that's in the same directory), you can just refer to it by name. Like `(require "foo.rkt")`. This works for any relative path. If you're not guaranteed to have a fixed relative path to the file, then you might need to use `dynamic-require`.

Comment: Thanks, that means I do not need to do anything in frawor.